# Conditionally add or append to a file in linux script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I need to modify a file via a script.
I need to do the following:
IF a specific string does NOT exist then append it.

So I created the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
if grep -q "SomeParameter A" "./theFile"; then  
echo exist  
else  
   echo doesNOTexist  
   echo "# Adding parameter" >> ./theFile    
   echo "SomeParameter A" >> ./theFile    
fi
```

This works but I need to make some improvements.
I think it would be better if I checked if "SomeParameter" exists and then see if it is followed by "A" or "B". If it is "B" then make it "A".
Otherwise append the string (like I do) BUT BEFORE the start of the last block of comments.
How could I do this?
I am not good in scripting.
Thanks!

Comment: a) What do you consider last block of comments? b) What do you mean "Some Parameter" is followed by "A" or "B", does it mean only a space or spaces are between them?

Comment: @bbaja42:a) There is a series of lines starting with `#` in the end of file commenting stuff.I would like to write before these if it is easy/possible. b) I am trying to make it robust and take into account the chance of having more than 1 space present

Answer (score 8):

First, change any `SomeParameter` lines if they already exist. This should work with lines like `SomeParameter` or `SomeParameter B`, with any number of extra spaces:

```
sed -i -e 's/^ *SomeParameter\( \+B\)\? *$/SomeParameter A/' "./theFile"
```

Then add the line if it doesn't exist:

```
if ! grep -qe "^SomeParameter A$" "./theFile"; then
    echo "# Adding parameter" >> ./theFile    
    echo "SomeParameter A" >> ./theFile    
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FLAG=0}
     /parameter a/{FLAG=1}
     END{if(flag==0){for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){print}print "adding parameter#\nparameter A#"}}' your_file
```

`BEGIN{FLAG=0}`-initializing a flag variable before the start of the file processing.

`/parameter a/{FLAG=1}`-setting the flag if the parameter is found in the file.

`END{if(flag==0){for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){print}print "adding parameter#\nparameter A#"}}`-finally adding the lines at the end of the file

Comment: If you could explain what you are doing it would be great!

Comment: @Jim...just that it doesnt have expalnation doesnt mean you should down vote.

Answer (score -1):

A perl one-liner

```
perl -i.BAK -pe 'if(/^SomeParameter/){s/B$/A/;$done=1}END{if(!$done){print"SomeParameter A\n"}} theFile
```

a backup theFile.BAK will be created (-i option). A more verbose version, which takes into account the last comments, to be tested. Should be saved in a text file and executed `perl my_script.pl` or `chmod u+x my_script.pl` `./my_script.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $done = 0;
my $lastBeforeComment;
my @content = ();
open my $f, "<", "theFile" or die "can't open for reading\n$!";
while (<$f>) {
  my $line = $_;
  if ($line =~ /^SomeParameter/) {
    $line =~ s/B$/A/;
    $done = 1;
  }
  if ($line !~ /^#/) {
    $lastBeforeComment = $.
  }
  push @content, $line;
}
close $f;
open $f, ">", "theFile.tmp" or die "can't open for writting\n$!";
if (!$done) {
  print $f @content[0..$lastBeforeComment-1],"SomeParameter A\n",@content[$lastBeforeComment..$#content];
} else {
  print $f @content;
}
close $f;
```

once it is ok then add the following:

```
rename "theFile.tmp", "theFile"
```

Comment: I need to do it from a spec file.I am not sure if I can use perl

Comment: sure, you can read it with perl, how do you read the spec file?